# NFT Contract receiving NFTs from other, unrelated NFT Contracts

Tags: receive

Imagine a contract A is deployed by Adress "Owner".

Then, an unrelated contract B sends NFTs to contract A's deployment address.

- **Is it possible for the Owner to do anything with contract B NFTs?**
- **Can contract A register the receiving of such unrelated NFT and trigger an event?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, sending ERC721 tokens to any contract needs the recipient contract to implement the `ERC721TokenReceiver` interface, otherwise, the transfer will fail.

Now talking about what you can do with the token, it all depends on how contract A is written. If it has the functionality of doing stuff with an ERC721 token then you can do that particular stuff. Yes, you can emit an event because the `ERC721TokenReceiver` interface contains a function `onERC721Received`  which is called every time a token is transferred, you can emit the event in this function itself.